# Select and change the values of elements in a matrix that are not returned by the indices

Tags: matlab

I want to change the values of elements that are not returned by the indcies by using `a(~idx)` as shown in this example, but it does not work. How to change the values for all the elements that are not returned by `idx`?

```
a=[1 2 3 4;5 6 7 8;9 10 11 12;13 14 15 16]   %4x4 matrix
idx = sub2ind(size(a), [2 3 4], [1 2 4])     %select indcies 
a(idx)=10                                    %Change values for selected indcies
a(~idx)=0                                    %Change values for not selected indcies
```

This is the output, which is as expected for `a(idx)=10`, but not as expected for `a(~idx)=0`

```
a =

     1     2     3     4
     5     6     7     8
     9    10    11    12
    13    14    15    16
idx =

     2     7    16
a =

     1     2     3     4
   100     6     7     8
     9   100    11    12
    13    14    15   100

a =

     1     2     3     4
   100     6     7     8
     9   100    11    12
    13    14    15   100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `a(~idx)` syntax works only if `idx` is a logical array.

Your particular case is easier solved by setting all values to 0 first, then the selected ones to 10:

```
a(:) = 0;
a(idx) = 10;
```

For the case that you want to preserve the original values at `idx`, as suggested in the comment below, create a temporary array first:

```
b = zeros(size(a));
b(idx) = a(idx);
a = b;
```

Comment: I was just showing a(idx)=10   as an example. I want keep only these values and set everything to zero. `a` is a hugh matrix that I want to turn off and on elements that are highlighted by these indcies.